# Liferay 6.0.6 CE login takes upto 25 sec to login after upgarde from Liferay 5.2.3 CE

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Old setup (Liferay 5.2.3) login time was around 3-5 sec but for Liferay 6.0.0 CE it is taking time around 20 sec.

I am upgrading my portal by using following properties in portal-ext.properties:

```
permissions.user.check.algorithm=5
image.hook.impl=com.liferay.portal.image.DatabaseHook
```

After upgrade I am converting the legacy permission to new algorithm by using Data-Migration tab in Control panel and restarting it with following properties in portal-ext.properties:

```
permissions.user.check.algorithm=6
image.hook.impl=com.liferay.portal.image.DatabaseHook
```

Comment: @Prakash K : Even I am surprised with this down vote. Anyway my question is valid and I am getting response. So thanks for supporting me.

Comment: May be you can include a little more in your question, like, 1) from which version you upgraded, 2) CE or EE, 3) can paste non-confidential properties of your portal-ext.properties. That would help in debugging more of this issue and not another down-vote :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we faced similar issue when upgrading from 5.2.X to Liferay 6, in our case the issue was that the permission algorithm was changed by us in the upgradation, in version 6, there is a new permission algorithm available.

If you run Liferay 6 with permission algorithm 5, you login process will be slow.

Comment: Thanks Felix for your hint. I will try this and post the update here soon.

Comment: Please check http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10958571 posted by John Ryder. As I am getting the same problem when converting permission algorithm.

Comment: Slow login problem is solved by changing algorithm to 6 in Liferay CE 6.1.0. Thanks for the valuable suggestion :)